# Kibana5: index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: number, boolean, date, ip or string

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

So I just started with ELK (actually just EK)
I uploaded my data using PHP and MySQL
I can see all of the data in Kibana but whenever I try to create a visualization except the maps I get:

```
No Compatible Fields: The "sample" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: number, boolean, date, ip or string
```

This is my index.
It clearly has the type number and string.

[image]

I also tried:
[Kibana5, index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615498/kibana5-index-pattern-does-not-contain-any-of-the-following-field-types)

which gives an error:
`Field Capabilities: 5 of 5 shards failed.`
To figure out the shards thing I tried:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason'
```

It outputs:

```
sample 1 p STARTED    
sample 1 r UNASSIGNED CLUSTER_RECOVERED
sample 4 p STARTED    
sample 4 r UNASSIGNED CLUSTER_RECOVERED
sample 3 p STARTED    
sample 3 r UNASSIGNED CLUSTER_RECOVERED
sample 2 p STARTED    
sample 2 r UNASSIGNED CLUSTER_RECOVERED
sample 0 p STARTED    
sample 0 r UNASSIGNED CLUSTER_RECOVERED
.kibana 0 p STARTED    
.kibana 0 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_CREATED
```

I have no idea what to do. I just started with ELK.
I have elasticsearch 5.4.1
Kibana 5.4
Please help :(

Comment: Are you sure the fields list is from sample index?

Comment: I renamed my data to sample index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the index-pattern, and recreate it

Comment: Worked.
Deleted the index and started from scratch.
Removed ELK, then reinstalled and reindexed and it worked like a charm.