# Kibana not recognizing Elastic Search date field

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I am an ElasticSearch / Kibana noob, and am trying my best to teach myself the fundamentals of this service. I am trying to insert some `Keyword` documents into my AWS ElasticSearch service. The document is pretty straightforward. It contains

- `created_at` a **datetime** field
- `updated_at`: a **datetime** field
- `keyword`: the actual keyword itself, a string such as `watercolors`
  or  `romanticism`
- `user_id`: the user who created this keyword

Using the Kibana dev console, I've defined the mapping for this index using a `PUT` request, and then sent this `GET` request to check that it is valid (`GET /keyword_index/_mapping/Keyword`):

```
{
  "keyword_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "Keyword": {
        "properties": {
          "_created_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "_updated_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "keyword": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "userId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've successfully inserted records into **`/keyword_index/Keyword`**, using the following `POST` request (from a Python script):

```
POST MY_ES_SERVICE_ADDRESS/keyword_index/Keyword/FzaGCiZl68/_create
{"keyword": "Comedy", "userId": "hjkJVM4TjD12N", "_created_at": "2017-12-28 02:52:14", "_updated_at": "2017-12-28 02:52:14"}
```

Here is a sample result from executing a `match_all` query:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 332,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "keyword_index",
        "_type": "Keyword",
        "_id": "HCQAm97kbs",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "keyword": "Controlled",
          "userId": "",
          "_created_at": "2017-10-12 06:01:14",
          "_updated_at": "2017-10-12 06:01:14"
        }
      },  ... more results below not shown...
```

However, Kibana doesn't recognize my datetime fields when I attempt to create an index mapping:

[image]

Moreover, when I inspect the fields within Kibana, I see a bunch of fields I did not create mappings for, nor inserted when I sent my `POST` request. And, more importantly, I don't see my date fields at all:
[image]

I found a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615498/kibana5-index-pattern-does-not-contain-any-of-the-following-field-types) here, but the accepted answer was to click a "refresh fields" orange button in the Kibana Management console, but I see no such thing.

Where did my date fields go? And why are they not recognized by Kibana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found the culprit. **Fields that begin with an underscore, such as `_created_at` do not show in Kibana, as I discovered in this [Github issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2551).**

I simply changed my mappings from `_created_at` to `created_at` and `_updated_at` to `updated_at` and this issue was resolved.

I don't really mind, since I understand the need to differentiate between internal and user-facing fields, but maybe some more prominent documentation within Kibana could help save us some headache and time?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue in the past.  That is indeed the reason.  I resorted to prefixing my timestamps.